# Angular Routing Problem after excel download

Tags: angular, angular7, exceljs, angular7-router

My Routing works if i dont download the excel file but if i download file and then use routing then it fails.

**The Line which seems to be problematic is this line:**

```
 **const Excel = require('exceljs');**
```

This line is inside function which download excel.
If I click on the back button, 
the current page and previous page both are shown on a new page and OnInit and constructor are not hit

```
<a  (click)="btnClick()" class="btn btn-default cancel-btn">Back</a>

btnClick() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/newPage');
};
```

I have tried this also,

```
<a  [routerLink]="['/newPage']" class="btn btn-default cancel-btn">Back</a>
```

But on new page, i can see selector of both pages,

```
 <oldPage></oldPage>
 <newPage></newPage>
```

then i tried this:

```
 I have tried ng Zone code too.

  btnClick() {
    if (this.inTheZone){
       this.inTheZone = false;
       this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/newPage']);
    })
  }
};
```

My routing code is like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'newPage', component: newPageComponent, data: { title: 'NewPage' }
}]
```

Please anyone help.

Comment: Can you please add your routing rules?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi have added routing code at the last

Comment: First of all check your console for any errors, then why are you using require('exceljs') in angular? this is not correct syntax.

Use this instead: 

import * as Excel from 'exceljs';

const myWorkbook = new Excel.Workbook()

Comment: consider providing https://stackblitz.com/ live version of what you have problem on, lead you to an answer faster.

Comment: Just to have a proper clue what you are looking for: You have a button -> click -> download Excel -> Excel is opened in the same tab -> Hit back button in the browser -> orginal tab appears . Sorry I didn't get the whole scenario what you are looking for and what you perceive as a problem. So, basically what is it you wanna see and what do you see. The first part you've described more or less accurate but the second I don't understand. Plus still an issue? Angular7?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your problem as Fmerco has said, is that you are using require, what will give you a crash in your app.

In Angular we use TypeScript and therefore we can use ES2015 at least.

That means that we use the module system from ES2015 that uses `import` as a keyword to retrieve information from modules.

`import { Workbook } from 'exceljs';`

And if you want to push a file to the client, you can't use a redirect (because that way you are breaking the SPA concept, and probably the routing), so you probably will want a library like `file-saver`.

```
workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((data) => {
      let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
      fs.saveAs(blob, 'CarData.xlsx');
});
```

You can find a very good tutorial in https://www.ngdevelop.tech/export-to-excel-in-angular-6/ and an example in https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs (are updated to Angular 8).